# Find PDF of Y from (constant) joint PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Given the following joint PDF:

$$
f_{X,Y}(t,s) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3} & 0\leq t\leq 1, -1\leq s\leq t \\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

I need to find $f_y(s)$

So according to defintion:

$f_Y(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(t,s) dt = \frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{1} dt = \frac{2}{3}$

Which is TOTALLY wrong since it's not even a valid density (doesn't integrate to 1). I believe I have some component missing here, but I can't see what. I guess it has something with the fact that $s$ is bounded by $t$ in some of the region, but I can't understand what to do with that.

Could anyone please enlighten me?  I really really wish to understand what's wrong with my way of thinking here.

Thanks!

Comment: Writing the joint density with full support in the integral would make this easy to understand: $$f_Y(s)=\int\frac{2}{3}\mathbf1_{0<t<1,-1<s<t}\,dt=\frac{2}{3}\int \mathbf1_{\max(0,s)<t<1}\mathbf1_{-1<s<1}\,dt=\cdots$$

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks, I am not sure though how to continue. I guess that $1_{0<t<1, -1<s<t}$ is and indicator, but Iv'e never used it in such cases. Can you please share more details?

Comment: The joint PDF is not constant (none is), for example $f_{X,Y}(0,\frac12)\ne f_{X,Y}(\frac12,0)$.

Comment: @superuser123 You should use the indicator in these cases to help you keep track of the bounds of the integral. Just rewrite the condition $0<t<1,-1<s<t$ to get $\max(0,s)<t<1\,,\,-1<s<1$. Now you can see that $t$ runs from $\max(0,s)$ to $1$ whenever $s$ runs from $-1$ to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integration is **not** from $t= 0$ to $t= 1$.  For $s< 0$, the integration is from $t= 0$ to $t= 1$ but for $s\ge 0$ the integration is from $t= s$ to $t= 1$.

Comment: Thanks, but, how did you see that?

Comment: Draw a graph of values for x and y.  x goes from 0 to 1 while y goes from -1 to x.  That region is the square with vertices (0, -1), (1, -1), (0,0), and (1,0), topped by the triangle with vertices (0, 0), (1, 0),  and (1, 1).  **For each y**,  if y< 0, x goes from 0 to 1 but if $y\ge 0$, x goes from x= y, on the left, to x= 1, on the right.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_Y(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(t,s) dt = \int_{s}^{1} \frac{2}{3} dt = \frac{2}{3}(1 - s),$$
which is indeed a proper density function for $s > 0$.

Note that for $s \le 0$ we have $f_Y(s)$ as you've calculated, hence

$$f_Y(s) = \begin{cases}\frac{2}{3}(1 - s), s \ge 0 \\ \frac{2}{3}, s < 0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: How did you come up with that?

Comment: check carefully the limits from your system. You have $t \in [0, 1]$ but that's not it, you also have $-1 \le s \le t$, which means that the least value of $t$ is $s$ and the most is $1$, hence the limits are $s$ and $1$.

Comment: @pointguard0 You have only considered the case $s>0$, so the pdf of $Y$ is incomplete.

Comment: @StubbornAtom you are right, thanks, just fixed it.